# bug(Mat Table): Sticky column loses the bottom border

Tags: material-ui, angular-material, screen-resolution, angular-material-table

Using angular material. On mat table the bottom borders disappear on body column sticky.

Reproduction
Components: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples
Steps to reproduce:

Go to the material examples website and go to the example Table with sticky columns
Expected Behavior
What behavior were you expecting to see?
Display the bottom border in the sticky column in Chrome as it does in Firefox.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC8Ws.png)

Actual Behavior
What behavior did you actually see?
The bottom borders disappear
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba3gk.png)

Environment
Angular: 14
CDK/Material: 14
Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Windows